Show that $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\tan^{-1}(x^2)}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} \, dx = \frac{1}{2}\pi \tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{2}}\right)$

Problem: Show that $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\tan^{-1}(x^2)}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} \, dx = \frac{1}{2}\pi \tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{2}}\right)$$

Some thinking before trying
At least we can show that the identity holds, since the taylor series of the integrand is pretty easy to derive and then you can just integrate it term by term. Also the RHS is just $\arctan$ so there's nothing really difficult. Still I have no idea how to approach it if the answer wasn't given..
I'm thinking of integration by parts, differentiating $\arctan$ and integrating $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}$ into $\arcsin x$.
I  realized that the taylor series of the integrand isn't that easy to derive... almost impossible to express in terms of $n$.
My attempt
here's how far I got. Inserting the Taylor series for $\arctan(x^2)$ we find $$\sum_0^\infty {{(-1)^n}\over {2n+1}} \{\int_0^1 {{x^{4n+2}}\over {\sqrt{1-x^2}}}\}$$ Now define $$a_k:=\int_0^1 {{x^k dx}\over {\sqrt{1-x^2}}}=\int_0^{\pi/2}(\sin t)^k dt$$ then $a_{k+2}=({{k+1}\over {k+2}})a_k$ with PI.
Hence $${{a_{2k}\over {a_0}}={{1\cdots (2k-1)}\over {2\cdots (2k)}}}$$ and we find $$\pi/2 \sum_0^\infty {{(-1)^n}\over {2n+1}} \cdot {{1\cdot 3\cdots(4n +1)}\over {2\cdot 4\cdots (4n+2)}}$$
Now it's probably something with $\arcsin x$ or ${{\arcsin x}\over {\sqrt{1-x^2}}}$. Also the angle $\pi/16$ seems to appear.

I made it for all $n>0$ (even not integer).

Let $I(a)= \int_0^{\pi/2} \tan^{-1}(\sinh a \sin^2t)dt$. Then
\begin{align}
I’(a)=&\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cosh a \sin^2t}{1+\sinh^2a\sin^4t}dt=\frac\pi4\text{sech}\frac a2
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
& \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\tan^{-1}x^2}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}{dx} \overset{x=\sin t}
=\int_0^{\pi/2}\tan^{-1}(\sin^2t)dt\\ = &\int_0^{\sinh^{-1}1}I’(a)da
= \frac\pi4 \int_0^{\sinh^{-1}1}\text{sech}\frac a2\ da\\
=&\  \frac\pi2\tan^{-1}\left( \text{sinh}\frac a2\right)\bigg|_0^{\sinh^{-1}1}
= \frac{\pi}{2}\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{2}}
\end{align}

could you show how you evaluate the integral for $I'(a)$?

@clathratus Note that $I’(a)
=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cosh a \csc^2t}{(1+\cot^2t)^2+\sinh^2a}dt$ and substitute $y=\cot t$

thanks a lot for the answer

Trying to work the antiderivative.
$$\tan ^{-1}\left(x^2\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n }{2 n+1}\,x^{4 n+2}$$
$$I_n=\int \frac{x^{4 n+2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx=\frac{x^{4 n+3} }{4 n+3}\,\,\, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},2 n+\frac{3}{2};2
   n+\frac{5}{2};x^2\right)$$ These integrals write
$$J_n=x \sqrt{1-x^2} \left(P_n(x)+\frac {a_n}{2 b_n}\, \sin ^{-1}(x) \right)$$ where, in $OEIS$, the $a_n$ and $b_n$ form sequences $A063079$ and $A061549$. I did not find any pattern in the polynomials $P_n(x)$ which are of degree $4n$.
With regards to the definite integrals
$$K_n=\int_0^1 \frac{x^{4 n+2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\,\, \Gamma \left(2 n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}{2 \,\Gamma(2 n+2)}$$ and
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n }{2 n+1}\,\,\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\,\, \Gamma \left(2 n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}{2 \,\Gamma(2 n+2)} \,t^n=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt t} \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{t+1}-1}{2}}\right)$$ Make $t=1$ for the result.
Edit
Making the problem more general, for $n>0$ ($n$ does not need to be an integer), using the same steps as above,
$$I_n=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\tan^{-1}(x^n)}{\sqrt{1 - x^n}} \, dx = $$
$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{n}\,\,\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{3 n+2}{2 n}\right)}\,\,\,\, _4F_3\left(\frac{1}{2},1,\frac{n+1}{2 n},\frac{2 n+1}{2 n};\frac{3}{2},\frac{3 n+2}{4 n},\frac{5 n+2}{4 n};-1\right)$$
Asymptotically, using Stirling approximation,
$$\frac {I_n}{_4F_3(\cdots)}=\frac{2}{n}+\frac{2 (\log (4)-2)}{n^2}+\frac{24-\pi ^2+3 \log ^2(4)-12 \log
   (4)}{3 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$  where (thanks to &Mariusz Iwaniuk)
$$\, _4F_3\left(\frac{1}{2},1,\frac{1}{2},1;\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4};-1\right)=\sec ^{-1}\left(\sqrt[4]{2}\right) \cosh
   ^{-1}\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)$$

Let’s start from $$I=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\sin ^2 t\right) d t$$
with its parametrised integral
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \tan ^{-1}\left(a\sin ^2 t\right) d t$$
Differentiating w.r.t $a$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
I^{\prime}(a) & =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin ^2 t}{1+a^2 \sin ^4 t} d t \\
& =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\tan ^2 t \sec ^2 t}{\sec ^4 t+a^2 \tan ^4 t} d t \\
& =\int_0^{\infty} \frac{u^2}{\left(1+u^2\right)^2+a^2 u^4} d u, \text { where } u=\tan t\\
& =\int_0^{\infty} \frac{u^2}{\left(1+a^2\right) u^4+2 u^2+1} d u
\end{aligned}
$$
Playing a little trick on the power $4$ by dividing both numerator and denominator by $u^2$ gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
I^{\prime}(a)&=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\left(a^2+1\right) u^2+\frac{1}{u^2}+2} d u \\
& =\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{a^2+1}} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\left(\sqrt{a^2+1}+\frac{1}{u^2}\right)+\left(\sqrt{a^2+1}-\frac{1}{u^2}\right)}{\left(a^2+1\right) u^2+\frac{1}{u^2}+2} d u \\
& =\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{a^2+1}} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{d\left(u\sqrt{a^2+1}-\frac{1}{u}\right)}{\left(u\sqrt{a^2+1} -\frac{1}{u}\right)^2+2\left(1+\sqrt{a^2+1}\right)} \\
& =\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{a^2+1} \sqrt{1+\sqrt{a^2+1}}}\left[\tan ^{-1} \frac{u\sqrt{a^2+1} -\frac{1}{u}}{\sqrt{2\left(1+\sqrt{a^2+1}\right)}}\right]_0^{\infty}\\&=\frac{\pi}{2 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{a^2+1} \sqrt{1+\sqrt {a^2}+1}} \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$
Then
$$
I=\frac{\pi}{2 \sqrt{2}} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+1} \sqrt{1+\sqrt{a^2+1}}} d a
$$
Letting $y=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{a^2+1}}$ gives
\begin{aligned}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+1} \sqrt{1+\sqrt{a^2+1}}} d a &=2 \int_{\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}} \frac{1}{y \sqrt{y^2-2}} d y\\&= \int_{\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}} \frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{y^2-2}\right)^2+2} d\left(\sqrt{y^2-2}\right)\\&= \sqrt 2 \tan ^{-1} \sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{2}}\end{aligned}
and hence
$$\boxed{I= \frac{\pi}{2}\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{2}} }$$
